# Create Chat Room Using socket.io in ionic3 and angular4

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic3

I am developing Chat App Using socket.io. Problem is that when creating a room, socket-id is added to the room and then MSG is sent to the room. The first MSG is sent to room perfectly but the second MSG is not sent to the room. The second MSG is shown on the server side.

**Server Side Code**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('A user connected');

   socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
       var romSocketId = room.sid;
        socket.to(romSocketId).join(room.roomName);
      //  roome = room;
        console.log('user joined room ' + room);
    });

socket.on('chatmessage',function(data1){
         console.log(data1.msg);
         console.log(data1.room);
         socket.broadcast.to(data1.room).emit('msgFromSever', {message: data1.msg});
});

socket.on("msgToClient", function(data) {
  var sidd = data.sid;
  console.log(sidd);
  // sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(sidd).emit('msgFromSever', {message: data.msg, socket_id: socket.id, adminID: data.adminLoginId});
    })


socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('Serve Start');
});
```

**Client Side code for Joining Room**

```
this.socket.emit('subscribe', {roomName:'room' +this.joinRoomNummber, sid : socketid});
```

**Client Side code to Send Msg**

```
this.socket.emit('chatmessage', {msg: this.input.msg, room: this.randomId});
```

Comment: what is ```randomId``` for room? shouldn't it be same as ```joinRoomNumber```?

Comment: this.joinRoomNummber or this.randomId same

Comment: so you are saying ```randomId``` have the same value for first message & second message

Comment: yes  randomId same for all time

Comment: can you share your sample code on an git repo?